# Adding new themes in VSCode doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just downloaded version 0.9.1 as I've been waiting for better theme support. I followed the instructions from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_customization-adding-themes), but nothing happens. I see the theme show up in the Color Theme list, but selecting it changes non of the keywords, tags, ect to the theme's colors. I downloaded the Twilight theme from [ColorSublime](http://colorsublime.com/?q=twilight) as an example. Anyone else getting this to work?

Comment: So I just created a JS file and noticed that the syntax is showing up correctly for my Twilight theme, but only for JS files. HTML, CSS, PHP, SQL, ect. only show the default Dark Theme for VSCode. Are TextMate themes not taking in the latest build?

Comment: Suggest to report this as issue on https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List

Comment: Great idea, thanks! Checked the issue list and found that others are having the same issue. There's a fix pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a fix on the way from the VSCode team.